# How to filter what is shown in the for-each loop in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I thought it would be as easy as tell the for-each to only select top_coach_sales_vw that has "Site" equal to "PB" but when I run the script it does not loop through any of the data in the XML.

I am escaping the single quotes because it is part of a php echo.

```
    <xsl:for-each select="NewDataSet/top_coach_sales_vw[Site==\'PB\']">
         <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="Site"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="Status"/></td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

XML:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <top_coach_sales_vw>
      <name>Mike</name>
      <Site>PB</Site>
      <State>Ready</State>
  </top_coach_sales_vw>

  <top_coach_sales_vw>
      <name>Bill</name>
      <Site>EL</Site>
      <State>Talking</State>
  </top_coach_sales_vw>

  <top_coach_sales_vw>
      <name>Ted</name>
      <Site>PB</Site>
      <State>Ready</State>
  </top_coach_sales_vw>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of all the problems in the provided code, and for a complete solution. :)

Comment: Minor point, but you can replace the `<xsl:value-of select="Site" />` with just `PB`, given that it's guaranteed to have the same value; it'll make your xslt slightly more efficient. Also, I'd recommend using the heredoc/nowdoc syntax for string literals in PHP when it's an XML document; saves you worrying about escaping stuff: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:for-each select="NewDataSet/top_coach_sales_vw[Site==\'PB\']">
> ```

**There are a few problems with this**:

1. There is no `==` operator in XPath. You probably want the `=` comparison operator.
2. `\'PB\'` **is syntactically invalid** -- you probably meant just `'PB'`
3. `NewDataSet` is the top element of the provided XML document. If the above `<xsl:for-each>` instruction is in any template that is not matching the root ( `/` ) of the document, the expression `NewDataSet/top_coach_sales_vw[Site='PB']` will not select any node, because this is a relative expression and will be evaluated off the current node (the one that the template matches).

**Solution**:

Use:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/NewDataSet/top_coach_sales_vw[Site='PB']">
```

Answer (score 1):

XSLT uses a single `=` as it's equality operator.

Also, you're selecting `Status` in your loop body, though the xml sample you list contains `State` elements - that's probably an oversight.

Comment: I thought that was one of the first things I checked but I will retest thanks for taking a look at my issue.